# Create a dict from a array in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

It seems pretty simple but I can't find a way to do so ...

I have an array in javascript like so

```
array = ["a","b","c"]
```

And I would like to build dynamically a new dict based on it to have something like

```
my_dict = {
   "a": null,
   "b": null,
   "c": null
}
```

it seems pretty basic but I can't get my head around this. I tried something like this:

```
my_dict = {}; 
for (let key in array){ 
  this.my_dist[key] = null; 
}
```

But unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Why would you want to initialize the properties to `null`? You don't even need initialization. You can use `my_dict["a"] = x` even if there's no `"a"` key in `my_dict`.

Comment: In that specific case `Object.fromEntries(array)` would work (as every string has only one char :)) But `Object.fromEntries(array.map(k => [k, null]))` would be the better option

Comment: I tried something like 
```
my_dict = {};

for (let key in array){
 this.my_dist[key] = null;
}
```

but it didn't work

Comment: well yea what was `this`

Comment: Use `of` instead of `in` and it'll work. Also you really shouldn't create a global variable here, prefix `my_dict` with `const`, and refer to it with `my_dict` (no `this.`)

Comment: As you basically found a solution already, I'll edit your version into your question and vote to close as "typo", as a working solution is just two chars away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Object.assign` and `map`

```js
const array = ["a", "b", "c"];

const obj = Object.assign({}, ...array.map((x) => ({ [x]: null })));

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use reduce function

```
let dict = your_array.reduce((map, init) => {
    map[init] = null;
    return map;
}, {});
```

Comment: btw I didn't minus from it but check ur code.. it doesnt work

Comment: I updated my answer i add ".key" with error sorry :D